# SQL return values if not null, return zero when null

Tags: sql, null, return-value

If this simple query return no results (NULL), it returns zero in one row, which is correct. If there are some results, query returns error 512.

How can I modify it to return the values if found and "0" if not?

```
select ISNULL( (select Name from NAMES
left join ADDRESS on NAMES.Name = ADDRESS.Person
where
NAMES.Name = myinput
) , 0) as Name
```

Comment: Try to replace a number `0` with a string `'0'`.

Comment: What should be returned if there are multiple names with no matching address? What should be returned if some names have matching addresses and some names don't?

Comment: this is because you are using the sub query as Expression so it 's not allowed to return multiple values  try to use IIF instead

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your inner query return more then one value, you should get an error since `isnull` can only handle a single value.
I suggest using a different approach. The code is longer but it will give you the correct results with any number of rows returned from the query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Name 
    FROM NAMES
    LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON NAMES.Name = ADDRESS.Person
    WHERE NAMES.Name = @myinput
)

SELECT Name
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT '0'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE)
```

Using your inner query as a cte allows me to write it only once.
Using the `NOT EXISTS` causes the second query in the `union` to only return `0` when the cte returned no results. Otherwise, you'll get the results from the cte.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the main query into CTE and now

```
with q as(
    select Name 
    from NAMES
    left join ADDRESS on NAMES.Name = ADDRESS.Person
    where
    NAMES.Name = myinput
)
select Name 
from q
union all
select '0' 
where not exists(select 1 from q);
```